# Individually align elements within a Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to create a frontend using ReactJS. The different components of the page are being created using [tabler-react](https://github.com/tabler/tabler-react).

I am trying to create a navigation panel using the [Nav component in tabler-react](http://tabler-react.com/documentation/#nav). The return function looks like this:

```
return ( 
            <Nav >
                <Nav.Item to='#' value="Item1" />
                <Nav.Item to='#' value="Item2" />
                <Nav.Item to='#' value="Item3" />
                <Nav.Item to='#' value="Item4" />
            </Nav>
         );
```

It is by default displayed one after the other in a row, starting from the left-most side of the screen.

**I wish to display the items in such a way that 'item1' and 'item2' are displayed in the left-most side and 'item3' and 'item4' get displayed at the right-most end.** I am facing trouble doing this.

I searched for a solution and understand that a style property can be set to the tags which can do things like justifyContent, alignment etc. I tried setting such style properties  to the individual tags inside , but it doesn't cause any change in the rendered page.

I am new to ReactJS and javascript in general. So I am not sure if this is a basic mistake I am doing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quick fix

```
return ( 
            <Nav >
                <Nav.Item to='#' value="Item1" />
                <Nav.Item to='#' value="Item2" />
                 <div style={{
                       marginLeft: 'auto'
                 }} />
                <Nav.Item to='#' value="Item3" />
                <Nav.Item to='#' value="Item4" />
            </Nav>
         );
```

Comment: Interesting, this seems to do the trick. Could you add why this worked? That would be helpful for me to understand.

Comment: New div element is added betwwen Nav Items with margin-left of auto which takes available free space betwwen Nav Items

Comment: So, if I wanted to align all the contents of the Nav bar to be a bit more to the centre of the screen (keeping this spacing added between), will it work if I add similar <div> elements at both ends?

Comment: You can select nav directly by using `.nav` css class it uses flexbox so if you want to center it completely then add `.nav{justify-content: center}` this is better approach

Comment: Adding elements that are specifically for styling seems a bit silly to me. Flex has all the tooling you need to achieve this without adding elements.

Comment: @DavidBarker Hi, what is the solution you propose? I am new to frontend development, so I am not much familiar with css functions. Thanks.

Comment: @IshwarVenugopal I've added it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous methods but I wouldn't recommend adding elements just for styling. A simple method is to select the element which should be the last element on the left with `nth-child(n)` and add `margin-right: auto` to it. You could do this with the next element if you wanted and apply `margin-left: auto` instead if you prefer.

HTML

```
<nav>
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav a:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```